# Have google finding .com instead of .ru

Tags: google-search-console

We have one site with some domains like `example.com`, `example.lt`, `example.ru`, `example.eu`.

When entered into a Google search for our site, it finds `example.ru`, but not `.com`, and all domains are redirecting to `example.com`.

We have robots.txt and sitemap.xml added to the website. Yandex and Yahoo searches correctly points to example.com.

Comment: If those domains are just aliases of the same website, you need to add canonical meta headers to all pages that would point to address of the same page with .com. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Google's content guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en), you can use a canonical URL to setting a preferred domain, and also do this with [Google webmaster tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231).

Put this link in your site header:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com">
```

Comment: seems that this not helped me.. :? still .ru domain in top 3 of search results.. and .com seams didn't find at all.. 
or it need to have more time? because it's almost 2days for this change.. :/ 
maybe there is any other things which I could do? :O

Comment: Did you [ask Google to recrawl your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en)? If so, and you followed the steps above, I guess you just have to wait. It can take some time, but you never really know with Google.

Comment: yup asked.. :? seems all fault goes to google... ;/ but its soo strange because other search angines from begining finds good domain example.com.. 
and the only one google finds as example.ru.. but from begining example.ru is just redirecting to example.com and I can't find or think any logical explanation why it is so.. :D

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to marked website domain in Google webmaster that .ru etc domain moved to example.com permanently